# Setting TextField Delegate to another Class from ViewController in Swift is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Now in viewController, I set the text field delegate to TextFieldDelegateViewController class which is a class I defined to handle textfield delegate methods. The viewController instance is passed through a closure as weak.

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfCreatures: UITextField!
{
    didSet{
        if let selectedIndex = delegate?.getSelectedIndexPath(){

            numberOfCreatures.delegate = TextFieldDelegateViewController(){
                weak var edit = self
                return edit!
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my **TextFieldDelegateViewController** class

```
class TextFieldDelegateViewController: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {


weak var editDetailsViewController:EditDetailsViewController?

init(closure: () -> EditDetailsViewController?) {
    self.editDetailsViewController = closure()

    print("Init... \(self.editDetailsViewController)")
}




func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    print("Writing.....")
    if textField.tag == 1{
        return handleEditingDescriptionField(with: string, shouldChangeCharactersIn: range)

    }else{
        return handleEmptyNumberOfCreaturesTextField(with: string)
    }

}
```

}

When I set the delegate to be self in view controller, delegate methods work fine, but in case I put it in a different class, they are not even invoked. I'm trying to set the delegate to another class since I have many delegate methods in view controller and I want to split them. Appreciate your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In follow code you create a local variable implicitly and assign it to delegate:

```
numberOfCreatures.delegate = TextFieldDelegateViewController(){
                weak var edit = self
                return edit!
            }
```

Any local variable exists only inside a scope where it was created. You have to store it somewhere. For example, you can store it as controller's variable:

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfCreatures: UITextField!
{
    didSet{
        if let selectedIndex = delegate?.getSelectedIndexPath(){
            textFieldDelegateController = TextFieldDelegateViewController(){
                weak var edit = self
                return edit!
            }
            numberOfCreatures.delegate = textFieldDelegateController
        }

    }
}

var textFieldDelegateController: TextFieldDelegateViewController?
```